# What is the relationship between repo and git?

Tags: android, git, repo

I mean, I'm really new to programming and I know that repo is a tool for working with Android projects remotely, and I heard that repo has a relationship with git.
Is it true?

Comment: You could start with reading [the information](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/repo/info) for the 'repo' tag that you just used.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [the documentation](https://source.android.com/source/developing.html):

> Repo is a repository management tool that we built on top of Git. Repo unifies the many Git repositories when necessary, does the uploads to our revision control system, and automates parts of the Android development workflow. Repo is not meant to replace Git, only to make it easier to work with Git in the context of Android. The repo command is an executable Python script that you can put anywhere in your path. In working with the Android source files, you will use Repo for across-network operations. For example, with a single Repo command you can download files from multiple repositories into your local working directory.

Comment: This is even included verbatim in the [tag:repo] tag description here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Repo is a tool which manages multiple git repositories used for Android (the open source project.) AOSP is made up of > 100 repositories, so this makes managing and working with them much easier. See http://source.android.com for more details.

Answer (score 0):

To work with the Android code, you will need to use both Git and Repo.

Git is an open-source version-control system designed to handle very large projects that are distributed over multiple repositories. In the context of Android, we use Git for local operations such as local branching, commits, diffs, and edits.

Repo is a tool that we built on top of Git. Repo helps us manage the many Git repositories, does the uploads to our revision control system, and automates parts of the Android development workflow. Repo is not meant to replace Git, only to make it easier to work with Git in the context of Android. The repo command is an executable Python script that you can put anywhere in your path.

Answer (score 0):

To work with the Android code, you will need to use both Git and Repo. In most situations, you can use Git instead of Repo, or mix Repo and Git commands to form complex commands. Using Repo for basic across-network operations will make your work much simpler, however.

See here for more details:

https://source.android.com/source/developing.html

https://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html